# Sanity check for Application level permissions for Microsoft Graph - in order to read the Content of a User's DriveItem

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am coding against the `Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK` and proofing out the ability to read a user's `GraphServiceClient.Drive` to create an `IDriveRequestBuilder.Items` where I am supplying a `File` facet ID to create an `IDriveItemRequestBuilder.Content`to read the content of the file which is located on a user's OneDrive for Business account.

My request call:

```
var driveItemSteam = await graphServiceClient.Drives[custodianAct].Items["01MPVS7H3LTYVLJEAP5ZG2XOZ5EGHI5I4R"].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

However, when making the request I get a general exception that is thrown:

> {Code: generalException
>   Message: Unexpected exception returned from the service.
>   }

I have also attempted to make the same call through Postman and there I get a **401 Unauthorized** with the following comment:

> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.

To handle the authentication I have implemented a Service/Daemon approach to return an `access_token`. I would just like a sanity check - That the `Microsoft Graph SDK` has application level permissions to read other user's files?

Comment: Hello Dave,
The Microsoft Graph SDK does support acquiring an app-only access token. However, there is a known issue with using this app-only token to download user files and we are actively working to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. Please let me know if there are any updates to the ETA of the roll out.

Comment: FYI. The fix to download file content using app-only tokens is now deployed.

Comment: @KashifTahir - I currently have my app register as a `Web app / API` within portal.azure.com - however whenever I try to retrieve a `Stream` for a file - I get an error: `{Code: generalException
Message: Unexpected exception returned from the service.
}`

Comment: I'm getting the same exception.